# Struggling to find the right WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I'm struggling with a SQL query and I need your help. To be honest, I'm starting to wonder if what I want to achieve can be done the way I did it so far but maybe your collective brains can come up with a better solution than mine and prove me I took the good way at the beginning (Or that I was totally wrong and I should start from scratch).

### The Dataset

A row has 4 important fields: `ItemID`, `Item`, `Priority` and `Group`. Those fields contain the only valuable piece of information, the one that will be displayed in the end.

As I'm using SQL Server 2008, I don't have access to the `LAG` and `LEAD` function so I needed to simulate them (Or at least, I did it because I thought it would be useful to me but I'm not so sure anymore). To obtain this result, I used the code from [this article from SQLscope](https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/) which provide you with a `LAG` and `LEAD` equivalent that I restrict to a set of row that have the same `ItemID`. This adds 7 new *functional* columns to my dataset: `Rn`, `RnDiv2`, `RnPlus1Div2`, `PreviousPriority`, `NextPriority`, `PreviousGroup` and `NextGroup`.

```
ItemID      | Item      | Priority  | Group     | Rn        | RnDiv2    | RnPlus1Div2   | PreviousPriority  | NextPriority  | PreviousGroup     | NextGroup 
--------    | -------   | --------  | -------   | -----     | ------    | -----------   | ----------------  | ------------  | -------------     | --------- 
16777397    | Item 1    | 5         | Group 1   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777403    | Item 2    | 5         | Group 2   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | 5             | NULL              | Group 2   
16777403    | Item 2    | 10        | Group 2   | 2         | 1         | 1             | 5                 | NULL          | Group 2           | NULL      
16777429    | Item 3    | 1000      | Group 3   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777430    | Item 4    | 5         | Group 1   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777454    | Item 5    | 5         | Group 4   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777455    | Item 6    | 5         | Group 5   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777459    | Item 6    | 5         | Group 6   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777468    | Item 8    | 5         | Group 7   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777479    | Item 9    | 5         | Group 4   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777481    | Item 10   | 5         | Group 4   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777496    | Item 11   | 5         | Group 6   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777514    | Item 12   | 5         | Group 4   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL      
16777518    | Item 13   | 5         | Group 8   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | 10            | NULL              | Group 8   
16777518    | Item 13   | 10        | Group 8   | 2         | 1         | 1             | 5                 | 100           | Group 8           | Group 1   
16777518    | Item 13   | 100       | Group 1   | 3         | 1         | 2             | 10                | NULL          | Group 8           | NULL      
16777520    | Item 14   | 5         | Group 9   | 1         | 0         | 1             | NULL              | NULL          | NULL              | NULL
```

### The problem

The problem in my SQL query is the `WHERE` clause. I will always filter the rows based on their `Group` column. But there are some subtlety. Whatever the number of `Group` an `Item` is member of, I want it to appear in **one and only one** `Group` based on these criteria :

1. If the `Item` appears in the same `Group` more than one time, only the line with the lowest `priority` should be returned. If an `Item` appears more than one time in the same `Group` but with the same `Priority`, then only the first occurrence should be kept *Example:* for `Item 2`, only the line with a `Priority` value of **5** should be returned;
2. If the `Item` appears in the `Group` but is also present in another `Group` with a lowest `Priority`, it shouldn't be displayed. *Example:* `Group 1` is selected as a filter. `Item 1` should be displayed but `Item 13` shouldn't because it is also present in `Group 8` with a lower `Priority` (`Item 13` would appear only in `Group 8`).

Note that this is just a sample. My real dataset has more than 3000 rows and some other cases are probably possible that I haven't listed in my sample.

### Unsuccessful Attempts

Like I said, there is one constant in the `WHERE` clause and that is the `Group` filtering.

- Because of the **criterion #2**, I can't simply start my clause like that : `WHERE Group = 'Group 1'` and I need to have something a bit more complex.
- I have tried the following clause without success : `WHERE Group = 'Group 1' AND (Group = NextGroup AND Priority < NextPriority)`. That works well in the case of an `Item` that is in no more that 2 groups. But for `Item 13`, it would return the first two rows. And if I add something like `AND NOT (CorrectedPriority >= PreviousPriority)` to the `WHERE` clause, I get no results at all.
- Last attempt so far : `(SiteName <> PreviousSiteName AND CorrectedPriority >= PreviousPriority)`. The problem is that I will never return a line where `Rn = 1` because `PreviousSiteName` will be equal to `NULL`. Adding a check on `NULL` doesn't work either. I must have bee tired when trying this particular clause because it's complete garbage.

I will continue to try and find the good `WHERE` clause but I have the feeling that my whole approach is wrong. I don't see how I could solve the problem when there are more than two entries for the same `Item`. It is worth noting that this query is used in a **SSRS** report so I could maybe use custom code to parse the dataset and filter the rows (Working with tables might help solving the issue of `Item`s with more than two entries). But if there's a SQL genius around here with a working solution, that would be great.

PS : if someone knows how to fix this table and can explain it to me, extra cookies for him. :D

### Edit :

This is the modified query that I'm using at the moment. I will consider using @Yellowbedwetter's latest query has it seems more robust.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT ItemID,
               Item,
               Priority,
               Group_,
               MIN(Priority) OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY item
                 ) AS interItem_MinPriority
          FROM (SELECT ItemID,
                       Item,
                       Priority,
                       Group_,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY Item
                               ORDER BY Priority ASC
                         ) AS interGrp_Rank
                  FROM Test_Table 
               ) AS TMP
         WHERE interGrp_Rank = 1 -- Exclude all records with the same item/group, but higher priority.
       ) AS TMP2
 WHERE Priority = interItem_MinPriority; -- Exclude which aren't the lowest priority across groups.
```

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen while that table change edit is good, it would be best if you performed all of your edits at once rather than multiple small ones, there is a lot left to fix in this post.

Comment: Did I get this right?: An item has a priority; the lower the value the higher the priority (1 = highest priority). Each item can be part of n groups, however, only the group with the lowest priority (= highest value) should be returned?

Comment: @NickA Duly noted.

Comment: @daZza : it's exactly that. I would just said it differently as I want to return a list of items (That are in the selected group and meet the requirements) rather than a list of groups. :)

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen : thanks for the edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly this should work

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT ItemID,
               Item,
               Priority,
               Group_,
               MIN(Priority) OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY item
                 ) AS interItem_MinPriority
          FROM (SELECT ItemID,
                       Item,
                       Priority,
                       Group_,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY Item,
                                        Group_
                               ORDER BY Priority ASC
                         ) AS interGrp_Rank
                  FROM Test_Table 
               ) AS TMP
         WHERE interGrp_Rank = 1 -- Exclude all records with the same item/group, but higher priority.
       ) AS TMP2
 WHERE Priority = interItem_MinPriority; -- Exclude which aren't the lowest priority across groups.
```

I don't know if your version of SQL Server supports MIN() OVER()..., but if not you should be able to work around that easily enough.

**Edit:** To handle tie breaks.

```
WITH TEST_TABLE (ItemID, Item, Priority, Group_) AS 
 (
 SELECT '16777397','Item 1','5','Group 1' UNION 
 SELECT '16777403','Item 2','5','Group 2' UNION 
 SELECT '16777403','Item 2','10','Group 2' UNION 
 SELECT '16777429','Item 3','1000','Group 3' UNION 
 SELECT '16777430','Item 4','5','Group 1' UNION 
 SELECT '16777454','Item 5','5','Group 4' UNION 
 SELECT '16777455','Item 6','5','Group 5' UNION 
 SELECT '16777459','Item 6','5','Group 6' UNION 
 SELECT '16777468','Item 8','5','Group 7' UNION 
 SELECT '16777479','Item 9','5','Group 4' UNION 
 SELECT '16777481','Item 10','5','Group 4' UNION 
 SELECT '16777496','Item 11','5','Group 6' UNION 
 SELECT '16777514','Item 12','5','Group 4' UNION 
 SELECT '16777518','Item 13','5','Group 8' UNION 
 SELECT '16777518','Item 13','10','Group 8' UNION 
 SELECT '16777518','Item 13','100','Group 1' UNION 
 SELECT '16777520','Item 14','5','Group 9'
 ) 

 SELECT ItemID,
        Item,
        Priority,
        Group_
   FROM (SELECT ItemID,
                Item,
                Priority,
                Group_,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                  ( PARTITION BY item
                        ORDER BY Group_ ASC -- or however you want to break the tie
                  ) AS grp_minPriority_TieBreak
           FROM (SELECT ItemID,
                        Item,
                        Priority,
                        Group_,
                        MIN(Priority) OVER
                          ( PARTITION BY item
                          ) AS interItem_MinPriority
                   FROM (SELECT ItemID,
                                Item,
                                Priority,
                                Group_,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                                  ( PARTITION BY Item,
                                                 Group_
                                        ORDER BY Priority ASC
                                  ) AS interGrp_Rank
                           FROM TEST_TABLE 
                        ) AS TMP
                  WHERE interGrp_Rank = 1 -- Exclude all records with the same item/group, but higher priority.
                ) AS TMP2
          WHERE Priority = interItem_MinPriority -- Exclude which aren't the lowest priority across groups.
       ) AS TMP2
  WHERE grp_minPriority_TieBreak = 1;
```

Comment: I have started using and testing your solution. I still need to fully understand how it works but so far, it looks like it's doing what I need to achieve. The only problem so far is that if I have `AND Group_ IN @GroupList`, an Item can appear in two different group if both have the same priority. I think it's something I need to fix on my end by tweaking the priorities or maybe by playing with the `Order By` clause of the interGrp_Rank column. I will keep you updated with my tests. :)

Comment: By the way, I meant to write "The only problem so far is that if I add `AND Group_ IN @GroupList` in the last `WHERE` clause, an Item can appear in two different groups if both have the same priority (And, thus, the same interItem_MinPriority)."

Comment: In fact, after some more testing, I get some duplicate results (Same item appearing in more than one group) even without changing the last `WHERE` clause. Your approach is definitively good and I just need to find the good tweak to make it work in 100% of the cases. :)

Comment: I think that I manage to tweak it to serve my purpose. I simply removed the `Group_` from the `PARTITION` clause used to get the `ROW_NUMBER`. That way, a given item will have different `interGrp_Rank` if he appears in multiple `Group_` and even if they have the same `Priority`. I still need to check more of the data to ensure that there are no loopholes but it looks like it's on the good way to the resolution. :)

Comment: Could you post the query that you are running? The interGrp_rank filter is meant to handle the first requirement. Or the scenario that you are getting duplicates?

Comment: I don't see a requirement in your question to handle where the same item is found in 2 groups, both with a minimum priority. You'll need to break that tie. See edit in answer.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake in my initial post. Criterion #1 should have been : "If the `Item` appears in the same `Group` more than one time, only the line with the lowest `priority` should be returned. If an `Item` appears more than one time in the same `Group` but with the same `Priority`, then only the first occurrence should be kept". After trying your edited solution, I can tell you that it does the same thing than what I'm doing (I will try to edit my OP to show the query). On more than 3000 records, the results are the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well

about these criteria

1. If the Item appears in the same Group more than one time, only the
   line with the lowest priority should be returned. Example: for Item
   2, only the line with a Priority value of 5 should be returned;
2. If the Item appears in the Group but is also present in another
   Group with a lowest Priority, it shouldn't be displayed. Example:
   Group 1 is selected as a filter. Item 1 should be displayed but Item
   13 shouldn't because it is also present in Group 8 with a lower
   Priority (Item 13 would appear only in Group 8).

**I think we can get the right result by using the minimum priority per item without considering the group of item , because in the two cases above we took the minimum priority of the item.**

so the following query might be helpful.(I tested it with your sample data)

```
with minPriority as
(
select ItemID, Item, Priority , Group_,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ItemId order by priority )rn  from Test_table 
)
select * from minPriority where rn=1
```

Comment: Your version works as well with only one flow. `Item 6` is returned two times, probably because it has the same `priority` in the two different `group`s. But this is my fault because I messed up my edit and didn't changed the first criterion (Which is now fixed). :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but something like..`select max(priority) as mp ..... From ... Where group = 'group1' and mp not in (select max(priority).... from ... Where group <> 'group1'

Apologies for the typing, on my phone no glasses :)

Comment: I will take a look at this solution. It might be one way to do it. :)